# Incrementing a streampos Object

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, filestream

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
for (std::streampos Position = 0; Position < 123; Position++)
{
    // Use Position to access something...
}
```

However, it appears that `std::streampos` does not have `operator++` overloaded.

Trying to use `Position = (Position + 1)` results in the following error:

```
ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second:
```

Is there any workaround for this, or do I have to rely on `long unsigned int` being big enough for files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try a [`std::streamoff`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/streamoff/), which represents an offset in a stream. It supports both pre- and post increment/decrement operators.

> The underlying type is implementation defined, but must be able to be consistently converted to both streamsize and fpos (**thus, to streampos too**)

Edit to Maxpm's comment: You can apply the `streamoff` to anywhere, be it `ios::beg` or an arbitary `streampos`. Apply it to `ios::beg` and it behaves like a normal `streampos`. Apply it to a `streampos` and you got `streampos+streamoff`.

Comment: What is the difference between a stream offset and a stream position?

Comment: A streampos is a position in a stream. A streamoff is an offset from such a position. :-)

Comment: @Bo: Woops, completely overlook Maxpm's comment, thanks for catching that and sry Max! ;)

Answer (score 7):

Use `+=`:

```
for (std::streampos Position = 0; Position < 123; Position += 1)
```

`+` doesn’t work because `operator +` is actually defined for `streampos` and `steamoff`, not `int`.

This means that two implicit conversions exist that are equally good: either your `1` could be converted to `streamoff` (which is probably a typedef for `unsigned long`). Or the `streampos` is implicitly converted to `streamoff` which then has `1` added.

Answer (score 5):

`std::streampos` is not a numeric type, although it supports conversion
to and from numeric types.  If you want to do arithmetic on the
position, you need to use `std::streamoff` (and specify the from
argument when calling seek).

Also, don't forget that you can't seek to an arbitrary position in
a file unless it has been opened in binary mode, and imbued with the "C"
locale.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this link while looking into how I can subtract from a `std::streampos` object:
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=187599

The suggested solution is using the defined operator overload `operator+()` or `operator-()` which work pretty well for me.

```
Position.operator+(increment_val); 
Position.operator-(decrement_val); // alternative
```

P.S.
It may be better to use `operator+()` than `operator-()` to avoid any problems related to sign change